# Ubuntu freezes when booting with Logitech C930e Webcam plugged in

Tags: webcam

I bought a Logitech C930e Webcam cause I needed to have a way to use Zoom for school. The Webcam connects to my desktop computer running latest version of Ubuntu 20.04 with a USB Type A plug.

This webcam gives me a lot of trouble. With the webcam plugged into the USB port, I boot Ubuntu, then login into my Ubuntu user account and the webcam starts blinking white light and the desktop screen freezes. To fix this freeze I have to unplug the webcam USB connection. Then Ubuntu immediately unfreezes and works normally.

To get Zoom with video, I plug the webcam back in, open Zoom, try to connect, and when I try to enable video, the computer sometimes freezes again. I unplug the USB, plug it back in. I have to keep going through this routine a few times on some days until I finally can get everything to work normally. Then after class I shutdown and when I have to boot again, the issues start all over again.

Is there some driver I can download or something that will make this webcam work trouble-free? I have all the "proprietary" repos enabled on my Ubuntu so I'm open to any driver that will fix this. Or maybe there is some other fix I can do?

My goal is to be able to keep the webcam USB cable plugged into my desktop computer and be able to boot, login, and just have it work without having to unplug it then plug it back in, etc. Is this goal unrealistic to have?

Comment: Is this in a VM? Are you plugging into USB2 or USB3 port? What if you try the other? Is your computer overclocked?

Comment: No VM. The port is blue colored so I think USB3? I have tried other USB ports and the problem is the same. The computer is stock Intel NUC i5, no overclock.

Comment: Is BIOS USB set to legacy, or something else? Yes, blue is USB3. Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact model # of your NUC.

Comment: Intel NUC Kit NUC8i5BEK (8th Generation). USB Legacy is enabled (check marked). dmidecode produced = BECFL357.86A.0073.2019.0618.1409. Should I try updating the BIOS?

Comment: I'm not sure how updating the BIOS would address this issue. This strikes me as a driver issue first and foremost. Nonetheless, I did update the BIOS but the issue is unchanged.

Comment: With the BIOS update, we try the obvious things first, then move on. Try booting to a Ubuntu Live 20.04.1 DVD/USB, then try the camera, and see if it works there. Report back.

Comment: It occurred to me that this may be a Wayland issue. I checked and sure enough I was in a Wayland session. I switched over to X Org and so far the issue hasn't reappeared. I'm going to give it a while to make sure before posting it as a fix. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Problem was reproduced on XOrg, it's not Wayland specific.

Comment: Status please...